# How to test and implement data layer in Google Tag Manager for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, dom-events, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol

We are using [enhanced eCommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) tracking by using data layer, to setup and test it in local environment. We can see page views in analytics but the event and impressions are not triggered. 
I tried using this:

```
dataLayer.push({ 
    'ecommerce': { 'Impression': [ { 'name': '${product.name}' ,'id': '${product.code}' }]}

});

dataLayer.push({
     'ecommerce': 
     { 'detail': 
        {    'products': 
                    [{ 
                        'name':  '${product.name}',  
                        'id': '${product.code}',
                        'variant': '${product.style}' 
                    }]
        } 
    } 
});
```

But I don't know how to test in local.
I have tested using Google tag manager Debug mode, but it shows datalayer has been pushed but I can't track that event in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In localhost used to check tracking by Google Tag Assistant

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk

I think it is best way to check datalayer

Comment: I know this is old, but this extension for chrome is also pretty useful: [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)

Answer (score 0):

At least for the impressions, it looks like you are not using the correct parameter name (you have "Impression", but it should be "impressions"). Impressions should be measured as such, taken from this guide, https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce:

```
// Product impressions are sent by pushing an impressions object
// containing one or more impressionFieldObjects.
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',                       // Local currency is optional.
    'impressions': [
     {
       'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',       // Name or ID is required.
       'id': '12345',
       'price': '15.25',
       'brand': 'Google',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'variant': 'Gray',
       'list': 'Search Results',
       'position': 1
     }]
  }
});
```

Comment: We cant track events 
function onCheckout() { 
 dataLayer.push({ 
  'event': 'cart', 
  'ecommerce': { 
   'checkout': {
    'actionField': '',
    'products': [{ 'name': '${product.name}', 
        'id': '${product.code}', 
        'variant': '${product.style}',
        'quantity': '${entry.quantity}'
       }]
    
    'eventCallback': function() { document.location = '/cart' ; }
      } 
     }
  });  


}
</c:when>

Comment: modified it but can you let me know where I can see this pushed data in google analytics

Comment: Are you sure the data is getting to Google? Just because you get it into the dataLayer, doesn't mean that the information gets to GA. You have to have some set of rules and tags in GTM that cause the data to be sent to GA. @legowife gives some good advice. Make sure the dataLayer contains all of the data you want to send to GA BEFORE you load your GTM container. Use a Google tag utility such as GA Debugger, Omnibug, ObservePoint, or a general HTTP debugger such as Fiddler or Charles Proxy to make sure that the correct data is sent to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented this for a client and found that omnibug (for firefox or chome) and google real-time reports were the best combination for testing once we'd set everything up.

I pretty much went by the book having my developer setup the datalayer (very important that this be above the GTM tag in your code!) and setting up the various macros, rules, and tags myself in GTM according to this documentation (different from your link): https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce It's easy to miss the collapsed tag manager configuration steps on that page. I know I did.

If you've implemented all of the GTM settings, then most of the enhanced ecommerce stuff should show up in omnibug when you initiate any of the actions that should trigger those events.

The piece we had the most difficult time with was product impressions as our product listing pages are ajax driven.

I also found Simo Hava's blog post on this very helpful! http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ecommerce-tips-google-tag-manager/

---

**Note:** For the record with our setup we use a separate container for production and development environments which is what enables us to publish and test out with omnibug. I find Simo's GTM Tools very useful for this too so I can just copy over select tags, macros, and rules: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/introducing-gtm-tools/

Good luck!

Comment: I prefer to use the same container for both development and production and use a macro to switch GA accounts based on domain. This way I don't have to duplicate container settings and avoid having to debug differences between them.

Comment: I think it's a preference/experience thing. I prefer omnibug and the like for initial testing because it's what I'm used to. It's only when I get into the weeds that I turn on the debugger. Ideally google will implement a method for publishing to separate environments (tealium does!) since they're aiming the tool at traditional marketers who would be more used to debugging with omnibug or tag assistant, but I won't hold my breath. Simo's tools fixed most of my problems with the double container method. It's still slightly tedious to make sure everything matches up, but much more fool proof.